# How to know when all AJAX call are complete?

Tags: jquery

On page load I need to call an API. When all AJAX call are finished (completed) I want do unlock UI. The problem is that I don't know how many times i will call API. It might be once or 10.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

           callAPI(yourApiKey);
});
```

and functions:

```
function getRates(yourAPIKey, contractCode, startDate, endDate) {
// I did cut some code here
 $.ajax({   
     url: ratesEnquiry,
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: "jsonp",
     jsonp: "callback",
     complete: function (response, responseCode) {       
     },
     success: function (json) {
     $.each(json, function (index, value) {
             populateValues("rate", this.ContractCode, this.RoomTypeCode, this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.RoomPrice);
             populateValues("hrate", this.ContractCode, this.RoomTypeCode, this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.RoomPrice);

             });
         }
     });
 }



function getAvailability(yourAPIKey, contractCode, startDate, endDate) {
    // I've cut off some code here as well
    $.ajax({
    url: availabilityEnquiry,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    //jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback",
    complete: function (json, responseCode) {
        //console.log(response); console.log(responseCode);
        //alert("complete");           
    },
    success: function (json) {

        $.each(json, function (index, value) {
             populateValues("avail", this.ContractCode, this.RoomTypeCode, this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.Quantity);
             populateValues("havail", this.ContractCode, this.RoomTypeCode, this.Date.substr(0, 10), this.Quantity);                      
            // alert(this.RoomPrice);
            });

        }
    });
}


function callAPI(yourAPIKey) {

     // I've cut off some code here

     $.blockUI({ message: '<span class="loader green" original-title="1Loading, please wait…"></span><h3> Please wait...</h3>' });
     $.ajax({
         url: enquiry,
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: "jsonp",
         jsonp: "callback",
         complete: function (response, responseCode) {
         },
         success: function (json) {
             $.each(json.Contracts, function (index, contract) {
                ContractsArray[Count] = contract.ContractCode;
                Count++;

             });
             for(var i = 0; i < Count; i++){

                 getAvailability(yourAPIKey, ContractsArray[i], startDate, endDate);
                 getRates(yourAPIKey, ContractsArray[i], startDate, endDate);

             }
         }
     });
    }
```

Can I use ajaxStop or ajaxComplete do sovle that?

Comment: Look at using the deferred object APIs. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object

Comment: You *could* use `.ajaxStop()`, though I'd say Matt Ball's suggestion of using the Deferred API is the better option.

Comment: Personally, if you have the ability to do so, I would change your API to return the full data needed with a single call rather than make a bunch of different API calls while the user sits there and waits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use counter and check if that for every call add 1 to that counter and for every finish minus 1 to that counter, and if counter will be 0, you know all api calls are finished
simple example:

```
var calls = 0;
function makeCall(url) {
   calls++;
   $.ajax({
      complete: function(resp) {
          calls--;
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: The potential problem with this solution is if the calls aren't started at the same time (e.g. if you are adding to the counter when the calls are made as in your example), one call may complete and bring the counter to 0 before other calls are started - triggering the function. Otherwise I can't see a problem with this. Pretty much reference counting..

Answer (score 0):

.ajaxComplete should work  It registers a handler for when ajax requests are completed.  Essentially, this handler is called whenever an ajax request completes.

Why would you think it doesn't work?

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/